# "Can't open *.sh" message while booting

Tags: linux, shell, startup, execution, init.d

When I run a script `S*.sh` at startup using `init.d` directory to link it to `/etc/rcS.d`, I get the following message:

> Can't open file `py.sh`

The `py.sh` is included in the `S*.sh` and should be executed. All files are set as superuser and and all users have the rights to read, write and execute. When I'm starting the `S*.sh` manually, it works fine.

Here is the code written in `S*.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
x=1
while [ $x -le 14400 ]
do
DD=$(date +%d)
MM=$(date +%m)
date >> /home/lasbr/Dokumente/"bmv"$DD$MM".log"
sh /etc/init.d/py.sh &
sleep 60s
x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

Maybe, because it works manually it is related to the sequence of booting. Maybe Ubuntu tries to start the script before several services which need to be running to handle the script?!

Comment: You are not sharing a whole lot of information and your question is confusing. Are you maybe calling y.sh without the absolute path and the `PATH` environment variable does not contain the path?

Comment: Which information do you need? I'm calling y.sh with the absolute path (/etc/init.d/y.sh)

Comment: Post the script minus all sensitive information.

Comment: What is `S*.sh`, is it literally, with wildcard or you're censuring your filename? You've so far `y.sh`, `py.sh` and `S*.sh`, does it mean you've 3 separate scripts? You've the error: `Can't open file y.sh`, but your script is called `py.sh`, can you provide missing info, how do you call this `y.sh` or it's typo?

Comment: If you want to debug your script, run with `-x`. For instance: `#!/bin/sh -x` and when calling, try: `sh -x /etc/init.d/py.sh`, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong file name. It's py.sh obviously. S* is just an example name. Full name of S*.sh is S13bmv.sh. Should I really debug while booting? Wouldn't the debugger show the same "Can't open" error? And again manually started it works...

Answer (score 1):

Check your include. You must provide the full path in the include, otherwise if you put just the name of the script, it will assume that the file should be in the current working directory which can be different from your script's location.

Comment: Great answer, however it's not complete as it is. Normally you should use the comment, however with lack of reputation, you should probably try answering some more clarified questions instead.

Comment: What do you mean with include? Isn't there already the path name (/etc/init.d/py.sh)?

Answer (score 0):

Call this script directly in **/etc/rc.local** to run it at start.

```
/etc/y.sh &>/dev/null &
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I found out, why the system hangs at startup. `Can't open py.sh` is not the main problem. The problem is the `while` loop, because the script wasn't launched in the background. The system waits until the `while`-loop is done (which takes 10 days) and then continues booting.

`Py.sh` accesses a device (battery computer) and this device can only be accessed with a running system. Of course it says that `py.sh` can't be found but meanwhile I just took the code out of `py.sh`and recognized that the system needs to be running to access the device.

Now the result of all this is the question: How can I launch a shell script in BACKGROUND on start-up?